# MCP - How can i use Pictures as Buttons in the Main menu?

Tags: java, image, minecraft, mainmenu

How can i use Pictures as Buttons in the Main menu? - For example as button for Singleplay like Sigma 5

So it looks like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vYpP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the buttons to be certain images I'd suggest making a resource pack. [Here](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/texture-packs/minecraft-resource-pack-template) is a link to a resource pack template, and you can find the blank button it uses and change it out for an image.